# How to find all stored procedures that delete rows from a particular table

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005

If there's a way of doing this without regular expressions, that's great. If there isn't, here's what I've got so far:

I've written a simple CLR user-defined function (which as you can see I've called `CLR_RegExMatch`) that performs regex matches on a supplied string. I use it to search for patterns inside stored procedures, triggers, functions etc.

Here's an example of its use - searching for inserts into a table called ExampleTable:

```
SELECT O.name, O.type_desc
FROM
    SYS.OBJECTS O
    INNER JOIN SYS.SQL_MODULES M ON 
        M.object_id = O.object_id
        AND dbo.CLR_RegExMatch('INSERT\s+(INTO\s+)?ExampleTable\b', M.definition) = 1
```

The issue I've got is that I can't come up with a regex pattern to find all routines that delete rows from a given table. Obviously I could substitute the following for the last line in the previous example:

```
        AND dbo.CLR_RegExMatch('DELETE\s+(FROM\s+)?ExampleTable\b', M.definition) = 1
```

and that gets me part of the way there. However it wouldn't pick up the following:

```
DELETE T1
FROM
    ExampleTable T1
    INNER JOIN AnotherTable T2 ON T2.ParentId = T1.Id
```

So what I'm looking for is either a regex pattern that will match deletes as above, or alternatively a different way of going about this.

---

N.B. The reason that I'm querying the `definition` column of `SYS.SQL_MODULES` instead of the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` is that the latter only contains the first 4000 characters a routine definition, whereas the former contains the full text.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

It will not tell you which procedures actually *delete* something from a table - but it will very easily and nicely find all procedures which reference that table in any way. Look at those and find those you need!

Comment: As explained in my question, I've already got all of the functionality that you attribute to that tool from the combination of a CLR regex function and the system tables. But I guess what you wrote could be useful to someone who's not willing to query system tables or write CLR functions. Also a nice SEO boost for the developers!

Answer (score 0):

If can help, i use this stored procedure that can find a string in all modules in the database/s

usage:

```
exec find_text 'text to search', 'db_name' 
-- if no db_name specified search in all DB
```

Code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[find_text]  
@text varchar(250),  
@dbname varchar(64) = null  
AS BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

if @dbname is null  
 begin  
  -- enumerate all databases.  
  DECLARE #db CURSOR FOR Select Name from master..sysdatabases  
  declare @c_dbname varchar(64)  

  OPEN #db FETCH #db INTO @c_dbname  
  while @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1   
  begin  
    execute find_text @text, @c_dbname  
    FETCH #db INTO @c_dbname  
  end    
  CLOSE #db DEALLOCATE #db  
 end 
else  
 begin 
    declare @sql varchar(250)  
    --create the find like command  
    select @sql = 'select ''' + @dbname + ''' as db, o.name,m.definition '  
    select @sql = @sql + ' from '+@dbname+'.sys.sql_modules m '  
    select @sql = @sql + ' inner join '+@dbname+'..sysobjects o on m.object_id=o.id'  
    select @sql = @sql + ' where [definition] like ''%'+@text+'%'''
    select @sql = @sql + ' order by o.name'  

    execute (@sql)  
 end   
END
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't get me any closer to the answer. As explained, I've got a good way of searching for text patterns throughout the stored procs, triggers etc.

Comment: The example i gave you **search in all stored procedures, triggers, user functions, ...** whatever in a db, give a try and check it:
`exec find_text 'DELETE ExampleTable', 'your_db_name'`

Comment: And the example that I gave you does exactly the same thing but better! See [the MSDN documentation on SYS.SQL_MODULES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) for more info.